# c++ Eigen making copy?

Tags: c++, eigen, symmetric

Let A be a symmetric matrix and let v be a vector. I extract from A a block of n columns starting from j and multiply it by v using

```
VectorXd a;
a = A.middleCols(j,n).selfadjointView<Lower>() * v // does not compile
```

As this does not compile, whereas this

```
a = MatrixXd(A.middleCols(j,n).selfadjointView<Lower>()) * v
```

does, I am wondering whether the second version makes a copy of

```
A.middleCols(j,n).selfadjointView<Lower>()
```

or performs the computation directly?

Thanks for any hint.

**EDIT:** I suspect the problem has something to do with argument types, as I get the error :

```
invalid argument type 'typename ConstSelfAdjointViewReturnType.... to unary expression'
```

Indeed, A is the argument of a function passed by const reference using either of

```
const MatrixXd& A 
const Ref<const MatrixXd>& A
```

Here is an example:

```
// this version doesn't compile
MatrixXd returnSymmetricMatrix(const MatrixXd& A, const VectorXd& v, const MatrixXd& B){
// B is a symmetric matrix

VectorXd a;
a = A.middleCols(3, 4).selfadjointView<Lower>() * v;
MatrixXd M(code_fill(){...}); 
// code_fill is the function filling the lower triangular part of a symmetric matrix
M.block(1, 2, 3, 4).triangularView<Lower>() += B.selfadjointView<Lower>();

return M;
}

// this version compiles
MatrixXd returnSymmetricMatrix(const MatrixXd& A, const VectorXd& v, const MatrixXd& B){
// B is a symmetric matrix

VectorXd a;
a = MatrixXd(A.middleCols(3, 4).selfadjointView<Lower>()) * v;
MatrixXd M(code_fill(){...}); 
// code_fill is the function filling the lower triangular part of a symmetric matrix
Matrix(M.block(1, 2, 3, 4).triangularView<Lower>()) += B.selfadjointView<Lower>();

return M;
}
```

**EDIT2** Regarding my initial question and the example I've added at the Edit section, I am a bit confused regarding the copying. As I understand the difference between the working and the non-working versions, the line

```
Matrix(M.block(1, 2, 3, 4).triangularView<Lower>()) += B.selfadjointView<Lower>();
```

works because its lhs tells to Eigen that M.block(1, 2, 3, 4).triangularView() is actually a matrix rather than a reference to a matrix. Otherwise, the operator += would through an error that this operator is not overloaded for .block(). So my original question is whether Matrix(...) only tells that it's a Matrix to enable the computation, or rather copy the ... into a Matrix? Thanks!

Comment: The expression compiles (and runs) fine for me. Can you double check and add any additional information needed?

Comment: Yes, the first one should work fine, I see it's using `M` instead of `A`...

Comment: Can you flesh it out to a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression:

```
A.middleCols(j,n).selfadjointView<Lower>()
```

does not create any copy.

On the other hand, to avoid a temporary for the result of the product, you can add `.noalias()`:

```
a.noalias() = M.middleCols(j,n).selfadjointView<Lower>() * v;
```

This is only needed for the immediate assignment of dense product to allow code like:

```
a = M * a;
```

to behave as expected.

**EDIT:**

regarding your compilation issue, the following compiles fine:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
  int n = 10;
  MatrixXd M = MatrixXd::Random(n,2*n);
  VectorXd v = VectorXd::Random(n);
  VectorXd a;
  a.noalias() = M.middleCols(2,n).selfadjointView<Upper>() * v;

  const Ref<const MatrixXd>& A = M;
  a.noalias() = A.middleCols(2,n).selfadjointView<Upper>() * v;
}
```

**EDIT2**

The following line:

```
MatrixXd(M.block(1, 2, 3, 4).triangularView<Lower>()) += B.selfadjointView<Lower>();
```

makes no sense as you are creating a temporary copy that you are assigning to. Recall that here `MatrixXd(whatever)` calls the `Eigen::Matrix` constructor. Also assigning a selfadjoint-view to a triangular-view makes no sense. I cannot even think about what could be a reasonable behavior for this. If you only want to update the lower triangular part, then do:

```
M.block(1, 2, 3, 4).triangularView<Lower>() += B;
```

In this case, `triangularView` behaves as a writing mask.

Comment: Many thanks for the .noalias() reminder, but in this case, I do not really understand why the .noalias() is needed since I compute a=M*v (rather than a=M*a). I am not trying to avoid the storage of a as I really need it for future computations. However, I am trying to avoid the copy of A.middleCols(j,n).selfadjointView<Lower>() and I am still puzzled why the first version works for you, as it doesn't for me (and yes the M instead of A is a typo here, not in my code).

Comment: This is because we cannot know at compile-time whether you are doing a=Mv or a=Ma, and even at runtime this is very difficult in the general case. So by default, a=Mv is evaluated as if there is aliasing between a and M or v, so: `tmp = M*v; a=tmp;`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's almost at it, but a little thing remains, that I added as the EDIT2 section.

Comment: Many thanks! I was confused with the use of .selfadjointView<>(). I thought it deals with the storage as well. So my goal was indeed to fill the lower triangular part of A with that of B, and I thought I was warning Eigen that B is symmetric.